# Node send text after X amount of time?

Tags: node.js, settimeout

Let's say you have a parking meter app. User selects an amount of time and pays. 20 minutes before their time is up you want to send them a text via Twilio that their time is almost up. I'm not concerned about the payment or text part. What's the best way to do the timing aspect in Node that triggers the function that sends the text 20min before their time is up? Im aware of `setTimeout`, but is this a scalable method of handling this? IIRC, setTimeout doesn't execute at exactly the end of it's timer, but is dependant on when it can execute within the event loop. Let's assume you may need a couple hundred timers running at once and your server is realtively busy with other users triggering other callbacks and async functions. Also, the text doesn't necessarily have to be sent at exactly 20min before their time is up, a couple minutes margin of error would be acceptable. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can use something like [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron), cloud functions, etc. Various ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into node-cron and cloud functions.